# System.InvalidCastException '<>c__DisplayClass18_0' to type 'INotifyPropertyChanged' in LUT only (Roslyn bug)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm having a very curious problem in which I have tests failing with:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> '<>c__DisplayClass18_0' to type
> 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged'.

However, when I run "debug test", tests are green, wether I run the debug from unit tests or live tests 'debug'. Therefore it's tricky to investigate. Furthermore I never had any problem using those `ICommand` implementation in the app.

**I should not have any `Exception` (I don't have any in unit tests, I have in live tests and VS doesn't reach (break) the exception in this case, even though it's happening). How should I go forward ?**

The cast problem happens at `ListenForNotificationFrom((INotifyPropertyChanged) _executeDelegate.Target);` in the class `DelegateCommandListen`.

Wether the `Action<T>` is a **private named function** (1) or a **local function** (2) or a **lambda** (2), its property `Target` is well defined, and should be casted to `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Where (1) works for both live tests and unit tests, and (2) works **only in unit tests**.

My `ICommand` implementation:

```
public class DelegateCommandListen : ICommand
{
    private readonly List<WeakReference> _controlEvent;
    private Action<object> _executeDelegate;

    public DelegateCommandListen(Action<object> executeDelegate, Predicate<object> canExecuteDelegate)
    {
        _controlEvent = new List<WeakReference>();
        ExecuteDelegate = executeDelegate;
        CanExecuteDelegate = canExecuteDelegate;
    }

    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteDelegate { get; set; }

    public Action<object> ExecuteDelegate
    {
        get { return _executeDelegate; }
        set
        {
            _executeDelegate = value;
            ListenForNotificationFrom((INotifyPropertyChanged) _executeDelegate.Target);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (_controlEvent != null && _controlEvent.Count > 0)
            _controlEvent.ForEach(ce => { ((EventHandler) ce.Target)?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty); });
    }

    public DelegateCommandListen ListenOn<TObservedType, TPropertyType>
        (TObservedType viewModel, Expression<Func<TObservedType, TPropertyType>> propertyExpression)
        where TObservedType : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        var propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertyExpression);
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == propertyName) RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        };
        return this;
    }

    public void ListenForNotificationFrom<TObservedType>(TObservedType viewModel)
        where TObservedType : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
        var memberInfo = GetMemberExpression(lambda).Member;
        return memberInfo.Name;
    }

    private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression(LambdaExpression lambda)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression body)
        {
            var unaryExpression = body;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
            memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        return memberExpression;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecuteDelegate == null || CanExecuteDelegate(parameter);

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            _controlEvent.Add(new WeakReference(value));
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            _controlEvent.Remove(_controlEvent.Find(r => (EventHandler) r.Target == value));
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => ExecuteDelegate?.Invoke(parameter);
}
```

Here is how I test the viewmodel:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NoTarget()
{
    var sut = new DummyViewModel();
    Assert.IsFalse(sut.IsSelected);
    Assert.IsFalse(sut.ListenWithoutTargetCommand.CanExecute(null));
    sut.IsSelected = true;
    Assert.IsTrue(sut.ListenWithoutTargetCommand.CanExecute(null));
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class DummyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _listenWith1TargetCommand;
    private bool _isSelected;

    public string Result { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (value == _isSelected) return;
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ListenWith1TargetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _listenWith1TargetCommand ?? (_listenWith1TargetCommand = new DelegateCommandListen(
                           s => { Result = "Executing listen command 1"; }, // lambda|local function|named function
                           s => IsSelected)
                       .ListenOn(this, o => o.IsSelected));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Full sources: https://github.com/mprevot/ReproLiveTests

Comment: It's not tricky to investigate.  Look at what the error message is telling you.  `<>c__DisplayClass18_0` appears to be an anonymous type, a type which it says it is unable to cast to `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @RobertHarvey 1) VS/Roslyn does not says that (your "it appears" is "cultural" not logic) 2) I don't know how you can investigate exactly when there's no break.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and ASh Did you see the sources ? I gave a full example.

Comment: There is a break: it's throwing an exception.  Forget about the case that works; it has no relevance unless you can use it to fix the broken case.

Comment: @Richardissimo I think I did it. I think it's clearer. I'm open to any other piece of advice.

Comment: Not at my computer, so can't check this, but... Where you initialise `_listenWith1TargetCommand`, try replacing the anonymous delegates with references to class methods. Those anonymous delegates are probably being compiled into the anonymous type which you're seeing mentioned in the exception (you can check using an assembly inspecting tool like ILSpy/Reflector). So it's not a surprise that the anonymous type can not be cast to `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Whereas references to methods on the ViewModel will probably give the expected target.

Comment: @Richardissimo Indeed, it works with named private functions. It does not with local named functions. It's as if the compilation processus is not the same with live tests and with unit tests. The lambda as argument in `ListenOn()` can remain a lambda.

Comment: I any case, lambda or named function, its property `Target` is well defined, and clearly should be casted to `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It looks like it's not a problem in my code but somewhere in Roslyn, which is used in different manners in live tests and in unit tests. Things happen as if few steps are being skipped in live tests.

Comment: I any case, lambda or named function, its property Target is well defined←That is correct... and clearly should be casted to INotifyPropertyChanged.←That is so wrong

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Sorry, but you are the wrong one. As OP stated, it works just fine in the debugger. The code you posted below has nothing to do with what the OP is doing. It's completely different.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Well, then you should go and try it. It works. OP is stating it just doesn't work when he does unit tests.

Comment: @SledgeHammer It **does work** in unit tests and production, it does **not** work in **live tests**.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü The cast `(INotifyPropertyChanged) _executeDelegate.Target` should be fine in both case, since it's the same object (the viewmodel). Only the `_executeDelegate` is different (wether it's named or lambda or local), and it **does work every single time in unit test and production case**.

Comment: @Soleil, finally you are online I have been waiting!!! Could you please pass the failing code

Comment: @EmrahSüngü the code is both in the question and the git repo ([https://github.com/mprevot/ReproLiveTests](https://github.com/mprevot/ReproLiveTests)).

Comment: @Soleil, I do have access to that repo and It works in my case. I was under the assumption that you were different methods.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Let's talk there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185153/roslynbug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Artur Spychaj (MSFT), tests fail because LUT (Live Unit Testing) modifies the lambdas to capture the coverage information and the compiler moves the lambda around into a separate class. And indeed this new class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**`this` is captured (as it is supposed to be) by the lambda with unit tests, but not with LUT.**

The workarounds are:

1. to pass `this` as a separate parameter of `DelegateCommandListen` if one want to keep a lambda
2. to use a named function instead of a lambda.

Answer (score -1):

We mortals usually do not get to see Roslyn bugs :) So it is important to try to solve the problem at hand by investigating rather than blaming the tools :)
I think Visual Studio is telling you the exact problem.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<>c__DisplayClass18_0' to type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged'.

Moreover, you almost solved the problem yourself. You mention that anonymous lambda is not working but named functions are working.

Let us work out your problem one by one. First of all what is the `Action<T>.Target` property. Just copy and paste from Visual Studio.

> The object on which the current delegate invokes the instance method,
>   if the delegate represents an instance method; null if the delegate
>   represents a static method.

So what do you think happens when you pass an anonymous lambda? How do we pass anonymous lambda in the first place? Well, you may already know, so I will just refresh everyone's memory. Compiler in the background creates a class, in your case `<>c__DisplayClass18_0` and sets the anonymous lambda as properties of the said generated class and passes it along as if they are named functions of a proper class! This is important.

What is going on in your case then? When you pass an anonymous lambda

```
ListenForNotificationFrom((INotifyPropertyChanged) _executeDelegate.Target);
```

_executeDelegate's.Target is a compiler generated class `'<>c__DisplayClass18_0'`, which does not implement, of course, `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`. This is what is going on. It is not a Roslyn bug, in fact it is exactly how it is supposed to be :)

Edit: Just adding a Debug screenshot. It is in Japanese but I guess you can clearly see that it is the same as OP's message.
[image]

Comment: Except when you try to reproduce it in the debugger, it works as the OP expected :) and you get the container class of IsSelected. I didn't try to do unit tests, I just tried to reproduce it in the debugger because I had the same theory as you. Both debug and release builds work as the OP suggested.

Comment: It appears that when you run a unit test, the behavior is different then when you run it in the debugger or standalone. This wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @SledgeHammer, Could you please explain how the followings `Target` property be cast into `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `Action<object> act = (x) => { }; var casted = (INotifyPropertyChanged)act.Target;`

Comment: Of course what you did won't work. That's entirely different then what the OP did. He passed in s => IsSelected where IsSelected is a member of a class that implements INPC. You passed in an empty action in a static method. Apples and pink flamingos to what OP did.

Comment: @SledgeHammer, I decided that I do NOT stand corrected :P I have cloned OP's repo and checked every test. My answer may not reflect what is happening in the test case because we have a DUmmy implementation but iI am 99% sure that live code has the same error as  I explained in my answer

Comment: Did you actually try to run live code? Obviously not.

Comment: @SledgeHammer, I can not run the live code as I do not have access the OP's original code, but looking at the `Exception`, online Test codes an more tests in my local Visual Stuido, I came to the conclusion, like I mentioned 99%, that the problem at hand is what I described in my question.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü You can have the Enterprise version for 3 month, hence the live tests.